# SQL CASE SUM gives me 0

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have this code:

```
SELECT category.category_id, SUM(
    CASE(category.parent_id)
    WHEN 0 
        THEN category_description.name 
    ELSE 0 
    END
) 
AS category_main 
FROM category 
LEFT JOIN category_description ON category_description.category_id = category.category_id
GROUP BY category.category_id;
```

The output gives me 0 in category_main

```
category_id      category_main
     1                 0
     2                 0
     3                 0
     4                 0
```

What i want is to get the name of the categories, as category_description.name contains the name of categories.

The desired result I want is:

```
 category_id     category_main
     1               Toys
     2               Gifts
     3               Cars
     4               For men
```

Comment: Do you really mean `SUM`, or did you mean `COUNT`?

Comment: Andrew, I don't really know, cause when i tested it with column that contains only numbers, it worked for me, but now that i need the text to be outputed I don't know how it must be done

Comment: You have provided desired result but you haven't provide the source data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SUM` is for numeric values. For your intended results, it appears a simple select will do:

```
SELECT
    c.category_id,
    CASE c.parent_id WHEN 0 THEN d.name END as category_main
from category c
    LEFT JOIN category_description d
        ON d.category_id = c.category_id
```

Comment: I suppose that he will get `null`-s in column `category_main` in this case.

Comment: wow!!! Ron I am so glad you helped me out. I was sitting and breaking my head for 2 days lol. thank you so much!!!

Comment: @HamletHakobyan no I didn't get all the nulls in my case, I just need to declare more CASE WHEN and that will be all. I got the results working just. Thank you all for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

This code`SELECT category.category_id,` change to `SELECT category.category_id, category_description.name,`

You must add new column for select in SQL query.